# Does SGMII contain MDIO?

Tags: ethernet, mii, gigabit, sgmii

When connecting a NIC (Intel I210-IS) to an gigabit ethernet switch with integrated PHYs (Marvell 88E6176) using the SGMII interface, I came across the following question:

Since SGMII is a serialized version of GMII, it should contain a serialized version of MDIO, right?

Can I therefore assume, that I will be able to configure the switch via the SGMII interface?

Answer (score 1):

MDIO is not a part of GMII or SGMII. SGMII does have some autonegotiation features, but it does not encapsulate MDIO.

Comment: +1 sgmii is just the serdes data interface, the mdio to a phy that implements sgmii is something different.